# dhtmlxGrid groupBy when column is hidden

Tags: javascript, grid, dhtmlx

I'm using dhtmlxgrid plugin and i want to do the grouping with a hidden column for that i use those line of code:

```
grid.setColumnHidden(0,true); //OR grid.setColumnsVisibility(true,false,false,false);
grid.groupby(0);
```

but in this two case the group didn't work for me , it's work only when i don't use setcolumhidden or setcolumnsvisibility
and for me i don't want to show that column in header and in rows , i want it to be shown only in group row 
any suggestion ?
Thanks,
Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try to use the second attribute of the groupBy() method, so that the "#title" of the group row will be in a non-hidden column.
For example:

```
myGrid.groupBy(0,["","#title","#cspan","#cspan"])
```